# CakePHP returning False on successful query

Tags: mysql, cakephp

in my model I have a basic statement

```
$query = $this->query(my statement);
if($query)
return true;
else
return false;
```

The query IS executed successfully as a record is added in the database.  But it's returning false?

I even tried returning "true" and "false", and printing value of the return, it was false.

What am I doing wrong?  This SHOULD work, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Majority of the time, CakePHP queries are validation errors, try:

```
if ( $query ) 
  debug($this->validationErrors); die();
```

Not sure what type of query you are trying to run, maybe post it here? 
You should try to avoid $this->query in CakePHP, below are some techniques to save/retrieve data in the model.

To save data to the database in CakePHP, use:

```
$this->save($data);
```

To retrieve data in the database, use:

```
$this->find('all'); or $this->find('first');
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  still very new to cake.  looking into save now.  thanks for your help!--that works!

Comment: Awesome! If you have any other questions, feel free to ask. Always here!

Comment: related to the $this->save().  It is working well, but I have run into an issue when trying to do more than one 'save' per database table. get this " Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Action.id' in 'where clause'" and SQL error: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `database`.`database_table` AS `Action` WHERE `Action`.`id` = '15''.  and I there is no SQL that I made that does that.  I'm guessing it's  Cake functionality, maybe to prevent dupes?  But I WANT to have more than one entry in a single call

Comment: basically I have a URL like this:  report.php?field=1&field2=1  .  for each field that has a value of 1 as opposed to 0, I want to create a ROW recording the action.  So later on I can do a COUNT(*) where Action='X'

Comment: Found it: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html, Model::saveMany.